# how can do this query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I convert this to eloquent ORM in laravel

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM chat 
    WHERE (userID = $session AND toID = $friendID) 
    OR (userID = $friendID AND toID = $session)  
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
 ) AS `table` ORDER by id ASC
```

Comment: It would be better if you show your database tables and explain what you are trying to achieve instead of asking user to convert your SQL to laravel

Comment: Please let's see your table structure and explain better what you intend to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (userID = $session AND toID = $friendID) OR (userID = $friendID AND toID = $session)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 ) AS table ORDER by id ASC";

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql))
```

$result variable contains your output. You must be use your DB class

```
use DB;
```